# Application getting deadlocked

Tags: java, multithreading, deadlock

My application runs into a deadlock after runnnig for some time. I took a thread dump and noticed all my application threads leaving one are stuck on the following state

```
"APP-Thread-20" prio=6 tid=0x0000000007414800 nid=0x1268 waiting on condition [0x000000000951f000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.$$YJP$$park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x00000000e0179568> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:156)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1987)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:399)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:947)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:907)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - None
```

The only thread that is in runnable state is stuck at a code that is using SAX Parser. Thread dump for that is given below

```
"APP-Thread-19" prio=6 tid=0x0000000007413800 nid=0x18b4 runnable [0x00000000094de000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.$$YJP$$socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(SocketInputStream.java)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:129)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:218)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:258)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:317)
    - locked <0x00000000e2f3fee8> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:697)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:640)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1195)
    - locked <0x00000000e2f3ff90> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.setupCurrentEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLEntityManager.startEntity(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.startPE(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.skipSeparator(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDecls(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDTDScannerImpl.scanDTDExternalSubset(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl$DTDDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.xerces.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser.parse(SAXParser.java:198)
    at com.test.Parser.Parser.parseDocument(Parser.java:33)
    at com.test.processor.LinkExtractor.extractLinksFromXml(LinkExtractor.java:222)
    at com.test.processor.LinkExtractor.process(LinkExtractor.java:102)
    at com.test.content.pipeline.PipelineProcessingTask.run(PipelineProcessingTask.java:76)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)

   Locked ownable synchronizers:
    - <0x00000000e017c3b8> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.ReentrantLock$NonfairSync)
```

All threads are working on series of tasks where parsing is just one of the tasks. Code for parsing is not synchronized and every thread is doing a new Parser().parse().

Is this problem centered around the SAXParser? or am I looking in wrong direction?

I have 3 thread dumps and in all 3 scenario is the same.

Heres the code for Parsing. Request is an httpMethod.

```
byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(req.getResponseBodyAsStream());
body = new String(data,"UTF-8").trim();
Parser parser = new Parser();
List<String> entries = parser.parseDocument(response);
```

Comment: can you post the code relevant to the Network call and SAX Parsing?

Comment: How did you detect deadlock? Wich tool did you use?

Comment: @asgs I am doing a simple http get to get content of a web page and then passing the response string to SAX Parser to extract all possible links

Comment: @Taky, I did not detect a deadlock but the application is stuck not doing any work even when there are jobs in queue. There is no exception in logs and there is ample space in heap.

Comment: @VarunPathak what is the responce object in you code snipped? How do you use string object?

Answer (score 3):

Your parser is waiting for input from the network, while it is blocking all the other threads.

Answer (score 1):

So there no deadlock in your application.

No task in the Queues. So all workers except one wait while some task put into the Queue.

One executive worker load XML source to parse via SAX. And looks like it is the slow operation. Probably XML can be huge or network slow.

Problem in environment. In some cause nobody put task into the Queue. Also review performance of loading XML via network.